# flask sqlalchemy+Postgres uniqueconstraint on multiple columns is treated as unique constraint on each column separately

Tags: postgresql, flask-sqlalchemy, unique-constraint

I am trying to create a multiple column unique key under flask + sqlalchemy with postgres as db. It worked with tinysql pretty well, but somehow postgres does not like it as much and creates a unique constraint per column and not for all of them together... Any idea how to fix it? Should I add another keyword to the unique constraint or an Index?

```
class XYZ(sqla.Model)
    id = sqla.Column(sqla.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    article_id = sqla.Column(sqla.Integer, sqla.ForeignKey('article.id'))
    story_id = sqla.Column(sqla.Integer, sqla.ForeignKey('story.id'))
    article_position = sqla.Column(sqla.Integer)
    __table_args__ = (
        sqla.UniqueConstraint('article_id', 'story_id', 'article_position', 
                              name='unique_article_story_pos'),
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a surprising solution.
I was batch committing a number of entities to db. For testing purposes I moved my commits to be per item.
Problem solved.
But why? and why didn't it happen when I ran the same script on TinySql db?